# Listing directory from database in order and showing sub folders and files. Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I know there are solutions out there for showing a windows directory of folders and files but mine is from a virtual directory within a database.

I have it so far that when you click a show me button it shows the directory path you are in 
e.g.
folder 1.1.1
folder 1.1
folder 1

it displays in this order but i want it to display the main directory at the top.
I would also like to be able to make the list of files clickable so that you can go straight to a specific file or folder when you click the show me button to make it easier for users to find the file they want.  Is it possible to display sub-directories without been inside them?

My code for displaying the directory path you are in is:

```
dim previousPos 
previousPos = 0
dim html
html = ""


    if not test.BOF then

do while not objRsU.EOF

'if previousPos = (test.Fields(2)) then
response.Write html & "<br />"
html = ""

'else

html = test.Fields(0) & "\" & html

'end if

previousPos = test.Fields(2)

test.MoveNext
loop
end if


set test =nothing
set try =nothing



ListFolderContents Server.MapPath("/"), 0 

sub ListFolderContents(path, level)     

    dim fs, folder, file, item, subFolders     
    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
    set folder = fs.GetFolder(path)      
    if folder.SubFolders.Count > 0 or folder.Files.Count > 0 then         

    'Display the target folder and info.         
    if level > 3     then             
    Response.Write("<h2>"& folder.Name &"</h2>" & html)         
    end if  

    'Display a list of sub folders.         
    for each item in folder.SubFolders             
    ListFolderContents item.Path, level  + 1
    next          

    'Display a list of files.

     Response.Write("<a<ul></a>" & html)      
     for each item in folder.Files
     Response.Write("<li><a href=""" & test.Name & """>" & try.Name & "</a></li>")
    next         
    Response.Write("</ul>" & html)


    end if 
end sub
```

This second part of the code displays the Main folder of the directory.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use something like this instead? It supports Classic ASP.

http://ckfinder.com/